# Why are specific versions of npm packages not being downloaded from upstream source?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We have an Azure Artifact feed with an upstream source of https://registry.npmjs.org/.

Through this Azure Artifact feed, I can download the following npm package:

- caniuse-lite@1.0.30001017

But I can't download the following version of the same package:

- caniuse-lite@1.0.30001016

If I go direct to npm (not through the artifact feed) I can pull both versions as expected.

Is there anyway to diagnose this issue further?

Comment: Hi, Not get your latest information, are the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Comment: Hi @Drew Williams, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: This is still blocking me

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT For reference, this is the command that fails when we use an .npmrc to route through Artifacts:
`npm i caniuse-lite@1.0.30001016`

Removing the .npmrc (direct to npm) works.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFTthis is causing major disruptions to our CI/CD. Any more input?

Comment: We've put this down to the retention policy on Artifacts.

Comment: @Drew Williams, did you find a solution to this issue? I see you discovered the root cause. We are having a similar problem.

Comment: Similar problem here too - upstream dependencies simply don't work via azure feeds unless I install the very latest version. That's fine for direct dependencies, but for transitive dependencies, I can't reasonably do that.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure as to why the issue happened... but I was able to solve it in my case by following these steps:

1. Navigate to "Artifacts" within Azure
2. Select your private NPM feed in the dropdown
3. Click on "recycle bin" at the top of the screen
4. Find the package which you're having trouble with
5. Click restore on the package version

Comment: Spot on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The download package version is driven by the one specifying the versions in the `package.json`. So what you could do is simply modify the `package.json` and run a `npm install` then. Be sure to clear out the `node_modules` directory before you do that. Then we could specific npm package version to download in the Azure DevOps pipeline. Please check this [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies) for more details.

Also, we could run `npm install <package>@<version>` to [install an older version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) of a package. We could add the `--save flag` to that command to add it to your package.json dependencies, or `--save --save-exact` flags if you want that exact version specified in your package.json dependencies.

Comment: I ran the latter command `npm install <package>@<version>` to recreate this behaviour. It simply doesn't pull through azure devops pipelines

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the setup you have but I had an issue where specific package where not being found and therefore couldn't be used.

Our Artifact was setup to get upstream feeds if local feed doesn't have the package.
So it was odd why it wasn't getting from the upstream feed.
Our Artifact feed was on a separate common project. Other projects are grabbing packages from the common project.

It turned out that the problem was the permissions setup from the other projects to the common project. It was Reader role only.
This was fine for packages that were already stored in the local Artifact feed but when it couldn't find one and went to get it from the upstream feed, it needed write permissions to write it to the local feed.